# Moved CVS Server. How do we change the host without checking everything out again?

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

We use CVS where I work, not only for code but also for word documents and stuff like that. Everyone uses the  Tortoise GUI to access CVS.

We recently moved our CVS server, so the IP address changed. Now all the downloaded modules don't link up. We could check everything out again with the new IP address, but some people didn't check in their new stuff before the move.

I know there are hidden "CVS" directories that hold the old IP address. If you guys don't know of a way to fix this using tortoise I'll just write something in Java to recursively update the CVS/ROOT file in each directory. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, just "manually" change all the `CVS/Root` files. Here's a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#From current directory, look for all CVS/Root files and change the contents to the given argument.

root="$1"
find . -path '*/CVS/Root' -exec bash -c "echo $root > \"{}\" " \;
```